# PHP Server Sent Events locking up every other request

Tags: php, angular, server-sent-events

I implemented a simple endpoint on my PHP server, I am subscribing to it in my Angular application using [Azure Event Source](https://github.com/Azure/fetch-event-source) to be able to send headers with the request.

Connection it self works and I get the stream back, but once the connection is established every other call locks up. They stay in "Pending" state until I close the connection to the SSE endpoint. I've tried `session_write_close();` but no help. Is there something I'm missing? Ideally once the connection is established I would not want it to effect any other calls. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

**PHP: Server Side Implementation**

```
public function newSSEEvent()
{
    session_write_close();
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store");
    $counter = rand(1, 10);
    while (true) {
           echo "event: Date\n";
           $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
           echo 'data: {"time": "' . $curDate . '"}';
           echo "\n\n";
 
        $counter--;
        if (!$counter) {
            echo "event: Ping\n";
            echo 'data: Last Ping' . $curDate . "\n\n";
            $counter = rand(1, 10);
        }
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

**Angular: Client Side Implementation**

```
  async getEvent(url) {
    await fetchEventSource(
      url,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          CustomHeaders
        },
        onmessage(ev) {
          console.log(ev);
        },
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: How is your php server set up? E.g. apache with php module? And how is it configured? I wonder if you have set it to only be allowed to run one instance or one thread?

Comment: @DarrenCook I got Apache 2.4 with PHP-FPM 8.1 running. It makes sense that your suggestion is the issue. When I did more research it seemed like general consensus was closing session write would allow miltiple instances to run. Didn’t work in my case.